# Revert a dollars to pounds conversion

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

My US company has a division in the UK and we occasionally like to see how a proposal will look in pounds versus dollars.

This code switches a specific range in accounting format from USD to GBP.

```vb
For Each cel In lookRng
    If cel.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
        cel.NumberFormat = "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    End If
Next cel
```

I tried to revert from GBP to USD using the same approach.

```vb
For Each cel In lookRng
    If cel.NumberFormat = "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
        cel.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    End If
Next cel
```

The screen blinks with no change to the formatting.

Comment: What is the result in the Immediate Window of `Debug.Print cel.NumberFormat`?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Excel is altering the `NumberFormat` changing `[$£-en-GB]` to `[$£-809]`.

Notice that the new `NumberFormat` contains double quotes.  The easiest way to convert the format to a string is to use `Replace()`to double the double quotes.

> ```
> ?Replace(ActiveCell.NumberFormat, Chr(34), String(2, 34))
> _-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-
> ```

```
Public Const UKNumberFormat  As String = "_-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
Public Const USNumberFormat  As String = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"


Sub SwitchNumberFormats(lookRng)
    Dim Cell As Range

    For Each Cell In lookRng
        If Cell.NumberFormat = UKNumberFormat Then
            Cell.NumberFormat = USNumberFormat
        ElseIf Cell.NumberFormat = USNumberFormat Then
            Cell.NumberFormat = UKNumberFormat
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed it perfectly

Comment: @VBABegineer No problem.  You may want to check out my edit.

Comment: @VBABegineer I had a typo.